# Django "ljust" built-in template tag not working

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I'm trying to use Django's ljust template tag but cannot get it to work: the length of article.excerpt never reaches 400 characters. What am I doing wrong?

```
<p class="card-text">{{article.excerpt|ljust:"400"}}</p>
```

Comment: If you look at the raw page source - you'll find it is 400 characters... if you're opening it in a browser though, consecutive spaces will be displayed as one...

Comment: Depending what you're trying to do... you may want to do something like add `style="width: 400ch"` to your `p` tag

Comment: @JonClements You are totally right. Thanks!